# Upgrade to Standard SKU - Microsoft recommends Standard SKU public IP address for production workloads

Tags: azure, vpn, azure-virtual-network

We have a Virtual Network Gateway with an IP attached.
It was setup as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/tutorial-create-gateway-portal).

Now we have this "alert":

```
Upgrade to Standard SKU - Microsoft recommends Standard SKU public IP address for production workloads
```

But I can't just upgrade the IP since it's dynamic and associated with the VGW. Is there a way to upgrade this IP without the IP changing? The VPN connection is allowed to go down for a short time.

Comment: check this [Msdocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/ip-services/public-ip-upgrade-portal) without changing public ip we can't upgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment [VPN gateway doesn't support changing the public IP address after creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/ip-services/configure-public-ip-vpn-gateway#change-or-remove-public-ip-address).

Unfortunately it is not possible to upgrade VPN Gateway IP address without changing an IP address.

[Zone-redundant and zonal gateways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-vpn-faq#can-i-request-a-static-public-ip-address-for-my-vpn-gateway) (gateway SKUs that have AZ in the name) both rely on a Standard SKU Azure public IP resource. Azure Standard SKU public IP resources must use a static allocation method.

To change IP address from Basic type you need to change VPN gateway to another SKU, go to the Configuration page for your virtual network gateway.

- Click the dropdown arrow to show the available gateway SKUs.
- Select the SKU from the dropdown.

When you change to another gateway SKU, you delete the existing gateway entirely and build a new one. Creating a gateway can often take 45 minutes or more, depending on the selected gateway SKU. In comparison, when you resize a gateway SKU, there isn't much downtime because you don't have to delete and rebuild the gateway. If you have the option to resize your gateway SKU, rather than change it, you'll want to do that. However, there are rules regarding resizing:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpn-gateway-settings#resizechange